# Upload image to oracle database asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I need to upload an image to an Oracle database from asp.net mvc 5.

I have created a blob field in the database to store the image, the database connection with ADO.NET, and the CRUD works OK, but I don't know how upload the image to the database.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to add specifics about supported image formats etc. to allow for more specific answers.  Also maybe a code sample of your persistance logic so that someone can show you an example in context.